# System Rate's Button is not working

Tags: windows-7

My windows system Rating is not working, it won't even show any error message.I just click on button and nothing will happen.

Where is the problem?

Comment: post the file "C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log"

Comment: is the issue solved?

Comment: No, There isn't any file named winsat.log in your given directory :(

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin and run **winsat -formal** Does this calculate the score?